# importing nested dictionary data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, json-normalize

If my json file looks like this...

```
!head test.json

{"Item":{"title":{"S":"https://medium.com/media/d40eb665beb374c0baaacb3b5a86534c/href"}}}
{"Item":{"title":{"S":"https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/autotune.html"}}}
{"Item":{"title":{"S":"https://nlp.stanford.edu/~socherr/EMNLP2013_RNTN.pdf"}}}
{"Item":{"title":{"S":"https://github.com/avinashbarnwal/GSOC-2019/tree/master/AFT/test/data/neuroblastoma-data-master/data/H3K27ac-H3K4me3_TDHAM_BP"}}}
```

I can import the data in pandas using...

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json("test.json", lines=True, orient="columns")
```

But the data looks like this...

```
Item
0   {'title': {'S': 'https://medium.com/media/d40e...
1   {'title': {'S': 'https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/a...
2   {'title': {'S': 'https://nlp.stanford.edu/~soc...
3   {'title': {'S': 'https://github.com/avinashbar...
```

I need all the URL in a single column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In this case it will be easiest to use `pandas.json_normalize` on the `'Item'` column of `df`
- Since you have a column of links, I've included the code to display it as clickable links in a notebook, or save to an html file.

```py
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import HTML  # used to show clickable link in a notebook

# read the file in as you are already doing
df = pd.read_json("test.json", lines=True, orient="columns")

# normalized the Item column
df = pd.json_normalize(df.Item)

# optional steps
# make the link clickable
df['title.S'] = '<a href=' + df['title.S'] + '>' +  df['title.S'] + '</a>'

# display clickable dataframe in notebook
HTML(df.to_html(escape=False))

# save to html file
HTML(so.to_html('test.html', escape=False))
```

Answer (score 1):

Valid json format of test.json

```
[{"Item":{"title":{"S":"https://medium.com/media/d40eb665beb374c0baaacb3b5a86534c/href"}}},
{"Item":{"title":{"S":"https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/autotune.html"}}},
{"Item":{"title":{"S":"https://nlp.stanford.edu/~socherr/EMNLP2013_RNTN.pdf"}}},
{"Item":{"title":{"S":"https://github.com/avinashbarnwal/GSOC-2019/tree/master/AFT/test/data/neuroblastoma-data-master/data/H3K27ac-H3K4me3_TDHAM_BP"}}}]
```

Use this code:

```
df = pd.read_json("test.json")
df['url'] = df['Item'].apply(lambda x: x.get('title').get('S'))
print(df['url'])
```

Output:

```
0    https://medium.com/media/d40eb665beb374c0baaac...
1            https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/autotune.html
2    https://nlp.stanford.edu/~socherr/EMNLP2013_RN...
3    https://github.com/avinashbarnwal/GSOC-2019/tr...
```